# How to append item to drop down and save

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following drop down list which I am able to append new listings to.

```
<script>
function Add()
{
 var x = document.getElementById("MySelectMenu");
 var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.value= document.getElementById("url").value;
    opt.innerHTML = document.getElementById("name").value; // whatever property it has
  x.add(opt);

}    </script>

<select id="MySelectMenu">

</select>
<button onClick="newSrc();">Load</button>
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
URL: <input type="url" name="url" id="url">
<button onclick="Add()">ADD</button>
```

What currently happens (for obvious reasons) is once the user closes the browser page, the list obviously returns to its previou state. How do I make it so the list remembers the appended items?

Comment: you can use indexeddb there is a great tutorial here http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-indexeddb--net-34673

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) to save local data for the user, whenever the user adds an item to the list update the local cookie and when the page loads for the first time after a user comes back use an onLoad event to load the items from the cookie into the list.

this ofcourse will only be saved on the BROWSER level for that user, meaning if the same user opens the page in a difrent browser or on a difrent device these changes will not be saved.

to save info on a global nature you will need server side proccessing.

Answer (score 0):

Since javascript or jQuery are front-end scripting languages, the changes made to a page will not be saved.

You would have to explicitly save the newly added items either in Cookies or Session using the following add-on plugins,

1. https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
2. https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin

And then handle the newly added elements when the page loads at a later time.

Comment: Thanks, very useful links, currently browsing them now :)